# Moving submenu in mobile responsive to top instead of bottom

Tags: magento2

What is the best way to move my sub category's menu from bottom to top?

In mobile responsive the menu is showing at bottom located at: `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation`

Comment: Please Improve your question with the Image & code to convey that where exactly you need help

Comment: i want to move the sub category menu to the top on mobile preveiw https://ibb.co/nsduX5 check picture attached, i want the user to be able to choose from the submenu right after the page is loaded and not scrolling to the bottom of the page to be able to see sub categories